# At StackExchange, is there a way to view all new questions for all of my sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I've been a member of StackOverflow for a few months and have just started discovering some of the other Q&A sites.

Now that I have signed up to ~5 different sites, what is the best way to view all new questions that are posted to the individual sites? Is there a feed which will display a list of new questions created from those from all of my Q&A sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/

but I would be very careful following *all* questions from a site, unless it is one of our much lower volume sites. Check

https://stackexchange.com/sites?sort=questionsperday&expand=true

To see how many questions per day each site gets on average.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a tag set which includes all 5 sites you have joined, using http://stackexchange.com. For example, this is the combined question list for the Trilogy: https://stackexchange.com/tagsets/5139/combined-trilogy.

Alternatively, you can use something like [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/) to combine multiple site questions RSS feed together.